# How to use overloading constructors but stay in the same JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to do two things. One that asks the user to press spacebar to start, and one that starts the game. I am trying to have two constructors, one that asks the user to press spacebar and one that starts the game. The problem is if I create two instructors, I get two different frames, instead of one frame that has both of these together.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class DuckHunt extends JPanel {

    private ImageIcon imgBackground, imgForeground, imgCursor;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private int score, hits;
    private double accuracy;
    private DecimalFormat df;
    private Font f;
    private static final int PANEL_WIDTH = 640;
    private static final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 480;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new DuckHunt();
    }

    public DuckHunt(String text) {
        // THIS IS WHERE IM TRYING TO DO THE SPACEBAR THING
        // how do I do it so it's all in one frame, instead of two seperate ones
    }

    public DuckHunt() {
        df = new DecimalFormat("#%");
        f = new Font("Neuropol", Font.BOLD, 18);

        imgBackground = new ImageIcon("images\\background.png");
        imgForeground = new ImageIcon("images\\foreground.png");

        imgCursor = new ImageIcon("images\\cursor.png");

        cursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(imgCursor.getImage(),
                new Point(imgCursor.getIconWidth() / 2, imgCursor.getIconHeight() / 2), "");

        setLayout(null);
        setCursor(cursor);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(this);
        frame.setTitle("Duck Hunt © Nintendo 1985");
        frame.setSize(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setFocusable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.drawImage(imgBackground.getImage(), 0, 0, this);
        g2.setFont(f);
        g2.setColor(new Color(128, 208, 16));
        g2.drawImage(imgForeground.getImage(), 0, 0, this);
        g2.drawString("SCORE:  " + score, 20, PANEL_HEIGHT - 50);
        g2.drawString("HITS:  " + hits, 250, PANEL_HEIGHT - 50);
        g2.drawString("ACCURACY:  " + df.format(accuracy), 450, PANEL_HEIGHT - 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use two constructors for this. End of problem. Instead in your main method call one window, perhaps a modal JDialog, and then create and display the main JFrame GUI after returning from the JDialog.

Comment: Another and perhaps better option: use CardLayout to swap view -- the press space-bar view first and then the game second.

Comment: Please see edits to answer. Please ask questions if anything is confusing.

Comment: Again, please see edit to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would adding more layers to produce the effect you want including

- extracting your Game JPanel away from the JFrame
- Create more JPanels, including one for the introduction view
- Display these separate JPanels as separate "views"
- This can be done by showing the introduction JPanel in a modal JDialog, even a JOptionPane, and the main game JPanel in the main JFrame that is only displayed after the modal dialog is no longer visible
- Or better (I think) swap views via a CardLayout. This allows you to swap card component "views" in the same top level window. You would need yet another JPanel to use the CardLayout as its layout manager, and then add your intro JPanel and your game JPanel to this card layout-using JPanel. The tutorial can be found here: [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).
- In the example below, I make use of a PropertyChangeListener. Swing components are wired to allow use of this by default, so why not take advantage of this. The intro's JButton does nothing more than notify any listeners that it has been pressed by calling `firePropertyChange(...)` on the component's property change support. Then in the main GUI, I listen for this property change and respond to it by swapping JPanels in the CardLayout.

For example:[image]

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DuckHunt2 extends JPanel {
    public static final String NEXT_CARD = "next card";
    private static final int PANEL_WIDTH = 640;
    private static final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 480;
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private DuckHuntIntro intro = new DuckHuntIntro();
    private DuckHuntGame game = new DuckHuntGame();

    public DuckHunt2() {
        setLayout(cardLayout);
        NextCardListener nextCardListener = new NextCardListener();
        intro.addPropertyChangeListener(nextCardListener);
        add(intro, intro.getClass().toString());
        add(game, game.getClass().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);
    }

    private class NextCardListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getPropertyName().equals(NEXT_CARD)) {
                cardLayout.next(DuckHunt2.this);
            }
        }
    }


    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        DuckHunt2 mainPanel = new DuckHunt2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Duck Hunt © Nintendo 1985");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DuckHuntIntro extends JPanel {
    private JButton startButton = new JButton(new StartAction("Press Button to Start"));
    public DuckHuntIntro() {
        startButton.setFont(startButton.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 40f));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(startButton);
    }

    private class StartAction extends AbstractAction {
        public StartAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DuckHuntIntro.this.firePropertyChange(DuckHunt2.NEXT_CARD, null, DuckHunt2.NEXT_CARD);
        }
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DuckHuntGame extends JPanel {
    // game code goes here

    public DuckHuntGame() {
        JLabel dummyLabel = new JLabel("Your Main Game GUI Goes Here");
        dummyLabel.setFont(dummyLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 16f));
        add(dummyLabel);
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, the same code above can be used to create the two window scenario that you initially requested again using a *modal* JDialog, and it could look something like:

```
private static void createAndShowGui2() {
    JPanel introPanel = new DuckHuntIntro();
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog((JFrame)null, "Duck Hunt", true);
    introPanel.addPropertyChangeListener(pcEvent -> {
        if (pcEvent.getPropertyName().equals(NEXT_CARD)) {
            // make dialog go away
            dialog.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    introPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
    dialog.add(introPanel);
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    dialog.setVisible(true);        

    // since the dialog is modal, all code flow stops here 
    // until dialog is no longer visible

    JPanel gamePanel = new DuckHuntGame();
    gamePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT));
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Duck Hunt © Nintendo 1985");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui2());
}
```

You might ask why I went through the trouble of using property change listeners, rather than having the intro JPanel call a method that is held within the main GUI telling it to swap views. The main reason for doing this is that it reduces unnecessary "coupling", unnecessary connectedness between multiple classes, and this makes your code safer, less bug prone, and easier to scale up in size. For instance because I did this, it was easy to convert the original code that used the CardLayout to the 2nd bit of code that used a modal JDialog since the intro JPanel has no direct connection to the main GUI, has no knowledge of what listeners will do once notified of its change in state, and most importantly, has no *need to know* this information.